# JQuery "$('div').hide() and .show" not working for a certain div?

Tags: jquery, html, conditional-statements, show-hide

I'm having a minor issue. I've got the jQuery `hide()` and `show()` functions working well on form selection values for normal `<div>` elements, but I have one `<div>` element (the first one) with some code that doesn't display when it's selected.

Here's the link for an example: http://www.shmoggo.com/3/diff.html

and here's the code: http://www.shmoggo.com/3/diff.txt (sorry, it was too long to create a code block)

Any advice at all would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it's because your IDs are incorrect : can't start with a number.

Comment: It's because you are HIDING all DIV's. And since there is a DIV isnide DIV#1 it gets hidden. So DIV#1 is shown, but the DIV inside is hidden!

Comment: Are you trying to show/hide the "*Upload Complete Artwork*" section?

Comment: Yeah, I just look at the source in Firebug, Marco Johannesen is correct. div#1 is shown correctly, but div#1 div is hidden. So that's not the incorrect IDs, but you should change them to proper ones.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the comments, all the advice has led me to the solution, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `div` with `id="1"` contains another `div` which is hidden by the generic `$('div').hide()` call - and not shown again ever after.

Also, nesting multiple `$(document).ready()` calls is unnecessary.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dd").change(function(){
        var selected= $("#dd option:selected").data('size');
        $('div').hide();
        $div_to_show = $('#'+ selected); // cache element for better performance
        $div_to_show.show();
        $('div', $div_to_show).show(); // show divs nested below current div as well
    });

    $('div').hide();
});
```

**Edit:** Also, quote @bobince:

> Also note that purely-numeric IDs are invalid in the HTML4 doctype you're using (and should generally be avoided for compatibility reasons)

You should absolutely listen to that.

Answer (score 2):

The divs with id 2 and 3 are simple divs with just image. The top level (i.e) only the div2 and div3 are shown or hidden based on the selection.

In the div 1, you have a number of inner elements which are also set to display:none because you are using a generic 
           $('div').hide();

Always use the id or class selector while selecting elements. Using generic statements should be avoided

Comment: Also note that purely-numeric IDs are invalid in the HTML4 doctype you're using (and should generally be avoided for compatibility reasons).